# Typecasting to a Base Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I am reading through the docs of c# and I am not able to understand this concept of Typecasting to base class.

> As in Java, you cannot use a reference to a base class to access the members and methods of a derived class even if the base class reference may contain a valid reference to an object of the derived type.
>
> **You can reference a derived class with a reference to the derived type implicitly**:

```
DerivedClass derived1 = new DerivedClass();
BaseClass base1 = derived1;`
```

what does the statement "you can reference a derived class with the reference to the derived type IMPLICITLY (what does implicitly mean in the context)"

for example if Derived class has a method say `derived_name()'

does it mean I cant do this so

`base1.derived_name()  // invalid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you don't need to explicitly cast the derived object to the base type.

```
DerivedClass derived1 = new DerivedClass();

// This is an implicit coversion:
BaseClass base1 = derived1;  

// This is an explicit conversion:
DerivedClass derived2 = (DerivedClass) base1;
```

Regardless of how you convert, you can't call a method defined in a derived class from a variable of the base type.  To call a method from a derived type, you'd need to explicitly cast to that type:

```
((DerivedClass) base1).derived_name();
```